# How to add style to a dynamic html element in React

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor

I am using the CkEditor for React control and it dynamically generates a html element when Link option is clicked. Is it possible to add styling to that dynamically generated html elements class in React?

Comment: Can you share some code of the generated element?

Comment: Below is the generated element.
<div class="ck ck-balloon-panel ck-balloon-panel_arrow_nw ck-balloon-panel_with-arrow" style="top: 297px; left: 530px;">

I need to add a z-index style to it
<div class="ck ck-balloon-panel ck-balloon-panel_arrow_nw ck-balloon-panel_visible ck-balloon-panel_with-arrow" style="top: 512px;left: 645px;z-index: 1400;">

Comment: I meant of where it gets created in react. As you post it now, it seems you can just add the styling inline. Please add some more context code, and preferably to your original post, since it's more readable.